# Canvas Colour Match Range

Tags: javascript, canvas

My current code scans canvas for a colour then removes it from the canvas and moves onto next pixel. What I would like to achieve is the intensity of the colours search. So we find similar colours aswell, not just one RGBA color.

Is this possible, here is my working code with one colour.

**Current code**

```
    //1-225
    threshold = 100;

    //Get Canvas Element Data
    imageData = context.getImageData(0, 0, canvasEl.width, canvasEl.height);
    data = imageData.data;

    //RGB
    color = [120, 82, 31, 1];

    for (var i = 0, n = data.length; i <n; i += 4) {
      if(data[i] === color[0] && data[i+1] === color[1] && data[i+2] === color[2]){
           data[i+3] = 1;
      }
    }

    context.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
```

Comment: @Kaildo My current code works, and checks the whole canvas,  it does not through an error.

Comment: Could you post a complete answer please Kaiido, would really appreciate it.

Comment: @Kaiido That was a typo my bad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Disclaimer**

This answer is based on OP's code and may not be the best way of doing it.

---

To check if the actual pixel is in the range you defined by threshold, you can use some if statement like-so :
`if(data[i]>=color[0]-threshold/2 && data[i]<=color[0]+threshold/2 && data[i+1]>=color[1]-threshold/2 && data[i+1]<=color[1]+threshold/2 && data[i+2]>=color[2]-threshold/2 && data[i+2]<=color[2]+threshold/2`

Or, for more clarity, you could make a function that will check this fork :

```
function isBetween(value, i){
    return (value>=color[i]-threshold/2 && value<=color[i]+threshold/2)
}
```

Then use it like so :

`if( isBetween(data[i],i%4) && isBetween(data[i+1],i%4+1) && isBetween(data[i+2],i%4+2) ){ doSomething() }`

For a complete example :

```js
var canvasEl = document.createElement('canvas');
var context = canvasEl.getContext('2d');
document.body.appendChild(canvasEl);
var imageData;

var img = new Image();
img.crossOrigin='anonymous';
img.onload = function(){
  canvasEl.height = 250;
  canvasEl.width = 400;
  context.drawImage(this, 0,0,canvasEl.width,canvasEl.height);
  imageData = context.getImageData(0, 0, canvasEl.width, canvasEl.height);
  }
// image by Levanne (https://www.flickr.com/photos/lfphotos/14282259549/) CC BY-SA 2.0
img.src = 'https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/te5g7s1lh122quy/1024px-Levanne_%2814282259549%29.jpg?dl=0';

var input = document.querySelector('input');
input.addEventListener('change', colorIntesityThreshold, false);


function colorIntesityThreshold(){
    var threshold = this.value;
    var data = imageData.data;
    var newData = new Uint8ClampedArray(data);
    //RGB
    var color = [50, 100, 255, 1];

    function isBetween(val, i){
      return (val>=(color[i]-threshold/2) && val<=(color[i]+threshold/2))
    }

    for (var i = 0, n = data.length; i <n; i += 4) {

      if( isBetween(data[i],i%4) && isBetween(data[i+1],i%4+1) && isBetween(data[i+2],i%4+2) ){

           newData[i+3]=0;
      }
    }
    var newImg = new ImageData(newData, canvasEl.width,canvasEl.height);
    context.putImageData(newImg, 0, 0);
}
```

```html
<input type="range" min="0" max="255" value="0"/>
```

Comment: the second argument for the second and third calls to `isBetween` should be `i%4+1` and `i%4+2` respectively